# java wait observer to complete

Tags: java, asynchronous, observable

i am quite new to java async function and observable all these. Is there anyway to make sure the async function return before proceeding?
I am currently using `Thread.sleep(100);` so that i can get the data i want, but i do not think it is appropriate .

my code:

```
    private void getGroupAllInfo(CallbackContext callbackContext){
        Log.d("executing: ", "getGroupAllInfo1");
        Observable observable = GsscFactory.executeGetZwaveAllInfo(this.sock, MationPlugin.gatewayId, MationPlugin.account, MationPlugin.password);
        observable.subscribe(t -> {
            System.out.print(t);
            MationPlugin.allInfo.put("data",t.toString());
            // callbackContext.success(t.toString()); 


        });
```

```
  public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    this.getGroupAllInfo(callbackContext);
    try{
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    callbackContext.success(this.allInfo.getString("data"));
}
```

I realized that i cannot assign variable inside the observable.subscribe(t -> {}), so i decide to put the data i want into a json object. If there is some alternatives, please tell me. ><

Comment: Even I'm new to java and coding, more like are you expecting a synchronous method here insteda

Comment: ya  observable.subscribe is asynchronous, is there any way i can let it run everything first then continue besides use a ```Thread.sleep(100);```?

Comment: Can you paste the `class Observable` and what `subscribe` returns? Also what is this `execute` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a MutableLiveData variable like:

```
    MutableLiveData<String> response = new MutableLiveData<String>();
```

Then create an observer that observes the response value changes like:

```
    // Create the observer which updates the response when a new value arrives.
    final Observer<String> nameObserver = new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable final String response) {
            // Update the UI like a TextView text or do whatever you want with your [response] value
            responseTextView.setText(response);
        }
    };

    // Observe the MutableLiveData, passing the observer.
    response.observe(this, nameObserver);
```

Then post your new value to the response variable in your background task like:

```
    response.postValue("response value");
```